# Using openssl library inside ReactJS code

Tags: reactjs, openssl

I want to get the Base64 encoded binary SHA-256 digest of a document that i upload using reactJS form:

```
 <input
          type="file"
          name="file"
          onChange={async (e) => {
            let selectedFile = e.target.files;
          //I want to convert my file here
          }}
        />
```

So i can pass the result to an API endpoint .
The script that i use to get the correct form of the document is  :

```
openssl dgst -binary -sha256 <document> | openssl enc -base64
```

I want to get the same output of this script inside a react JS code . Or pass a document , that i upload using a form , to this script and then use the output .

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a library to compute the sha256, such as [crypto js](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js) and then

```js
let selectedFile = e.target.files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (event) {
   var data = event.target.result;
   var digest = CryptoJS.SHA256( data );
};
reader.readAsBinaryString(selectedFile);
```

Comment: I get this error 
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Failed to execute 'readAsBinaryString' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'

Comment: i cannot get the final result of this operation